# substring, after last occurrence of character?

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I have a column named phone_number and I wanted to query this column to get the the string right of the last occurrence of '.' for all kinds of numbers in one single sql query.

example:

515.123.1277

011.44.1345.629268

I need to get 1277 and 629268 respectively.

I have this so far:
select phone_number,
case when length(phone_number) <= 12
then
substr(phone_number,-4)
else
substr (phone_number, -6) end
from employees;

This works for this example, but I want it for all kinds of formats.

Comment: You've tagged this for Oracle, SQL Server, and MySQL, each of which have a very different set of functions for manipulating strings.  Which database are you actually using?  Or are you looking for three completely different answers?  From a normalization standpoint, the fact that you want to get one component of a longer string makes me suspect rather strongly that you've made a normalization error and that the column you're trying to parse is not atomic.

Comment: Hello justin, i am using the oracle database 11g. I edited the tags appropriately. I'm using sql plus for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be as easy as this regex:

```
SELECT phone_number, REGEXP_SUBSTR(phone_number, '[^.]*$')
  FROM employees;
```

With the end anchor `$` it should get everything that is not a `.` character after the final `.`. If the last character is `.` then it will return `NULL`.

Comment: How can you get everything before last occurrence of character (e.g., "Hello How Are You?" --> "Hello How Are")

Comment: @Growler - Ask it as a question and I'm sure someone can help you.

Comment: Sorry. How can you get everything before last occurrence of character (e.g., "Hello How Are You?" --> "Hello How Are") `?`

Comment: I mean, create a StackOverflow question, not ask a question as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Search for a pattern including the period, `[.]` with digits, `\d`, followed by the end of the string, `$`.

Associate the digits with a character group by placing the pattern, `\d`,  in parenthesis (see below).  This is referenced with the subexpr parameter, `1` (last parameter).

Here is the solution:

```
SCOTT@dev> list

  1  WITH t AS
  2    ( SELECT '414.352.3100' p_number FROM dual
  3    UNION ALL
  4    SELECT '515.123.1277' FROM dual
  5    UNION ALL
  6    SELECT '011.44.1345.629268' FROM dual
  7    )
  8* SELECT regexp_substr(t.p_number, '[.](\d+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) end_num FROM t
SCOTT@dev> /

END_NUM
========================================================================
3100
1277
629268
```

Comment: What if there are letters in the phone number? Also you can escape the period like so `\.` rather than putting it in a character class.

Comment: @David Faber True, an escaped period could/would do the job and I did that with digits. With respect to non-digits, I did not see/read that in the requirement. btw, nice answer.

Comment: it wasn't a requirement and I doubt you will see many phone numbers these days with letters in them. But someone could always have a vanity number. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in oracle:

```
select regexp_substr(num,'[^\.]+',1,regexp_count(num,'\.')+1) last_number from
(select '515.123.1277' num from dual union all
select '011.44.1345.629268' from dual );
```

Previous to 11gR2 you can use `regexp_replace` instead `regexp_count`:

```
select regexp_substr(num,'[^\.]+',1,length(regexp_replace (num , '[^\.]+'))+1) last_number from
(select '515.123.1277' num from dual union all
select '011.44.1345.629268' from dual );
```

Comment: You need not escape the `.` in a character class; you can simply do this: `[^.]`

Comment: Yes @DavidFaber, you are right, scape it's not necessary. Thanks :)

Comment: I tend to overescape myself, just in case :)

Comment: same happens to me :)